Relationship between the Hessian and Variance?
I am trying to understand the reason behind the famous relationship as to why the Hessian is related to the Variance.
I tried to work through this and it was very convoluted. I tried to summarize my work below in multiple parts. I start with the following:

Likelihood function: $ L(\theta|x) = p(x|\theta) $
Log-likelihood function: $ l(\theta|x) = \log L(\theta|x) $
Score function (first derivative of log-likelihood): $ s(\theta) = \frac{\partial l(\theta|x)}{\partial \theta} $
Hessian (matrix of second partial derivatives): $ H(\theta) = \frac{\partial^2 l(\theta|x)}{\partial \theta \partial \theta^T} $
Assumption: The score function has zero mean: $ E[s(\theta)] = 0 $
Fisher Information: $ I(\theta) = E[s(\theta)s(\theta)^T] = -E[H(\theta)] $

Taking a Taylor expansion of the score function around the true parameter value $\theta_0$:
$$ s(\hat{\theta}) \approx s(\theta_0) + H(\theta_0)(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0) $$
Since $\hat{\theta}$ is the Maximum Likelihood Estimator (MLE), we know that $s(\hat{\theta}) = 0$. Substituting this:
$$ 0 \approx s(\theta_0) + H(\theta_0)(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0) $$
Rearrange the equation:
$$ \hat{\theta} - \theta_0 \approx -H(\theta_0)^{-1}s(\theta_0) $$
Take the variance of both sides:
$$ \text{Var}(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0) \approx H(\theta_0)^{-1} \text{Var}(s(\theta_0)) H(\theta_0)^{-1} $$
Now, we use the fact that $\text{Var}(s(\theta_0)) = I(\theta_0)$ (this is the definition of Fisher Information):
$$ \text{Var}(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0) \approx H(\theta_0)^{-1} I(\theta_0) H(\theta_0)^{-1} $$
We know that $I(\theta) = -E[H(\theta)]$. For large samples, we can approximate $H(\theta_0) \approx -I(\theta_0)$.
Substituting this:
$$ \text{Var}(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0) \approx (-I(\theta_0))^{-1} I(\theta_0) (-I(\theta_0))^{-1} = I(\theta_0)^{-1} $$
Since $\text{Var}(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0) = \text{Var}(\hat{\theta})$ (because $\theta_0$ is a constant), we can conclude:
$$ \text{Var}(\hat{\theta}) \approx I(\theta_0)^{-1} \approx (-H(\theta_0))^{-1} $$
Thus:
$$ \text{Var}(\hat{\theta}) \approx \frac{1}{-H(\theta_0)} $$
Is this the correct reasoning?
Now, I will try to expand on some of these assumptions used above, i.e. why they are true. I hope my notes will be useful for students in the future that will study these topics.  I am not sure how to properly format everything, ideally all these extra justifications should be collapsible so that someone reading them could expand and collapse them as needed.


Justification: Why $s(\hat{\theta}) \approx s(\theta_0) + H(\theta_0)(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0)$.

Start by expanding $s(\hat{\theta})$ around $\theta_0$ using a Taylor Series:
$$ s(\hat{\theta}) \approx s(\theta_0) + J_s(\theta_0)(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0) + \text{higher order terms} $$
The Jacobian of the score function is actually the Hessian of the log-likelihood function (i.e. the first derivative of the first derivative is the second derivative of the original function):
$$ J_s(\theta) = \frac{\partial s(\theta)}{\partial \theta^T} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^T}\left(\frac{\partial l(\theta|x)}{\partial \theta}\right) = \frac{\partial^2 l(\theta|x)}{\partial \theta \partial \theta^T} = H(\theta) $$
Therefore, we can write:
$$ s(\hat{\theta}) \approx s(\theta_0) + H(\theta_0)(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0) + \text{higher order terms} $$
$$ s(\hat{\theta}) \approx s(\theta_0) + H(\theta_0)(\hat{\theta} - \theta_0) $$


Justification on why: $I(θ) = -E[H(θ)]$

Recap the Hessian and Fisher Information:
$$ H(\theta) = \frac{\partial^2 l(\theta)}{\partial \theta \partial \theta^T} $$
$$ I(\theta) = E[s(\theta)s(\theta)^T] $$
Write the expectation of the Hessian:
$$ E[H(\theta)] = E\left[\frac{\partial^2 l(\theta)}{\partial \theta \partial \theta^T}\right] $$
Exchange the order of expectation and differentiation:
$$ E[H(\theta)] = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta \partial \theta^T} E[l(\theta)] $$
On the right hand side, focus on the expectation of the log-likelihood:
$$ E[l(\theta)] = \int \log p(x|\theta) p(x|\theta) dx $$
Differentiate both sides with respect to $\theta$ (i.e. use chain rule and distribute the integral):
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} E[l(\theta)] = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log p(x|\theta) p(x|\theta) dx + \int \log p(x|\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} p(x|\theta) dx $$
The first term on the right is the expectation of the score function, which we know is zero.
Differentiate again with respect to $\theta^T$:
$$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta \partial \theta^T} E[l(\theta)] = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log p(x|\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta^T} p(x|\theta) dx + \int \log p(x|\theta) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta \partial \theta^T} p(x|\theta) dx $$
The first term on the right is $E[s(\theta)s(\theta)^T]$, which is the Fisher Information. The second term can be shown to be zero (it involves integrating $\log p(x|\theta)$ times the second derivative of $p(x|\theta)$, which cancels out). Therefore, we have:
$$ E[H(\theta)] = -E[s(\theta)s(\theta)^T] = -I(\theta) $$
$$ I(\theta) = -E[H(\theta)] $$


Justification on why $H(\theta_0) \approx -I(\theta_0)$.

Recap:
$$ H(\theta) = \frac{\partial^2 l(\theta|x)}{\partial \theta \partial \theta^T} $$
$$ I(\theta) = E[s(\theta)s(\theta)^T] = -E[H(\theta)] $$
The observed Fisher information, which is the negative Hessian evaluated at the MLE $\hat{\theta}$:
$$ J(\hat{\theta}) = -H(\hat{\theta}) $$
For large samples, the MLE $\hat{\theta}$ converges in probability to the true parameter value $\theta_0$. This means:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} P(|\hat{\theta} - \theta_0| > \epsilon) = 0 $$
for any $\epsilon > 0$, where $n$ is the sample size.
As a result, for large samples:
$$ J(\hat{\theta}) \approx J(\theta_0) = -H(\theta_0) $$
For the expected value of $J(\hat{\theta})$:
$$ E[J(\hat{\theta})] = E[-H(\hat{\theta})] $$
For large samples, we can approximate this as:
$$ E[J(\hat{\theta})] \approx E[-H(\theta_0)] = I(\theta_0) $$
Combining the above:
$$ -H(\theta_0) \approx J(\hat{\theta}) \approx E[J(\hat{\theta})] \approx I(\theta_0) $$
Therefore:
$$ H(\theta_0) \approx -I(\theta_0) $$


Justification on why: $\int \log p(x|\theta) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta \partial \theta^T} p(x|\theta) dx = 0$

Start with the integral:
$$ \int \log p(x|\theta) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta \partial \theta^T} p(x|\theta) dx $$
Use integration by parts:
$$ u = \log p(x|\theta) $$
$$ dv = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta \partial \theta^T} p(x|\theta) dx $$
Then:
$$ du = \frac{1}{p(x|\theta)} \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} p(x|\theta) dx = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log p(x|\theta) dx = s(\theta) dx $$
$$ v = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} p(x|\theta) $$
where $s(\theta)$ is the score function.
Applying integration by parts:
$$ \int \log p(x|\theta) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta \partial \theta^T} p(x|\theta) dx = \left[ \log p(x|\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} p(x|\theta) \right]_{-\infty}^{\infty} - \int s(\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} p(x|\theta) dx $$
The first term on the right side is zero because $p(x|\theta)$ and its derivatives approach zero as $x$ approaches $\pm \infty$ (assuming well-behaved probability distributions).
For the second term:
$$ - \int s(\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} p(x|\theta) dx = - \int \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log p(x|\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} p(x|\theta) dx $$
Now, note that:
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} p(x|\theta) = p(x|\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log p(x|\theta) = p(x|\theta) s(\theta) $$
Substituting this in:
$$ - \int s(\theta) \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} p(x|\theta) dx = - \int s(\theta) p(x|\theta) s(\theta) dx = - E[s(\theta) s(\theta)^T] = -I(\theta) $$
But we know from the properties of probability density functions that:
$$ \int \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta \partial \theta^T} p(x|\theta) dx = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta \partial \theta^T} \int p(x|\theta) dx = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta \partial \theta^T} 1 = 0 $$
Therefore, the original integral must be zero:
$$ \int \log p(x|\theta) \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta \partial \theta^T} p(x|\theta) dx = 0 $$


Justification on why $E[s(θ)] = 0$.

Write the score function and its expected value:
$$ s(\theta) = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log p(x|\theta) $$
$$ E[s(\theta)] = \int s(\theta) p(x|\theta) dx $$
Substituting the definition of $s(θ)$:
$$ E[s(\theta)] = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \log p(x|\theta) \cdot p(x|\theta) dx $$
Using chain rule:
$$ E[s(\theta)] = \int \frac{1}{p(x|\theta)} \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} p(x|\theta) \cdot p(x|\theta) dx $$
The $p(x|θ)$ terms cancel out:
$$ E[s(\theta)] = \int \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} p(x|\theta) dx $$
Interchange the order of integration and differentiation:
$$ E[s(\theta)] = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \int p(x|\theta) dx $$
The integral of a probability density function over its entire domain is always $1$:
$$ E[s(\theta)] = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} 1 = 0 $$
Therefore: $E[s(θ)] = 0$

1/2. I didn't go through every single one of your equations to check that they are correct, but I think you have it right. I would honestly say that these are normal difficulties when studying the asymptotics of the MLE. It's a very tough pill to swallow when you first encounter it because there are a lot of elements interacting together that need to be carefully considered (using vague terminology on purpose here). I don't think there is a clearer proof than what you wrote.

2/2 Maybe this alternative proof is easier?? Consider the pseudo-estimator: $\hat \theta = \theta_0 + H^{-1}(\theta_0) s(\theta_0)$ (maybe a sign error? depends on notation and direction of optimization). This is not a real estimator since we cheat by using the value of $\theta_0$^. It is immediate that this estimator has the right variance. Furthermore, replacing $H(\theta_0)$ by its empirical is valid (law of large numbers). Finally, using the standard analysis for convergence of the Newton optimization algorithm, this estimator converges to the MLE if the MLE is consistent

NB: proving the convergence of the MLE to my $\hat \theta$ pseudo-estimator is quite hard.

@Guillaume Dehaene: Thank you for your kind words of encouragement .... I really appreciate it :)

You're welcome! Best of luck and bon courage with your studies. Statistical asymptotics are a very fun topic once you get past the initial difficulties
